# Use parallelStream foreach to create HashMap, But sometimes value is empty

Tags: java, thread-safety, java-stream

Java Code Like :

```
List<Detail> DbDetails = ... Like 50000 rows records
Map<Long, List<Detail>> details = new HashMap();

DbDetails .parallelStream().forEach(detail -> {
        Long id = detail.getId();
        details.computeIfAbsent(id, v -> new ArrayList<>()).add(detail);

    });

Then ...

details.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
        e.getValue(); // Some value is empty
    });
```

I guess it because HashMap is thread-unsafe, so I use Hashtable instead of it. Then it run ok, all value has value, but I don't know why?

Comment: `HashMap` javadoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is pretty clear on this, "Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HashMap` is not thread-safe, so don't use parallel streams with it.

Besides, why do that there, when streams can do it for you?

```
DbDetails.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Detail::getId))
```

Comment: Thanks very much!! I learned a new way of writing it. I do that because I need to judge by the conditions then create two different list, And I didn't know I could do like that.